# How allocate memory on Kernel mode by windbg?

Tags: windows, debugging, memory, windbg

How allocate memory on Kernel mode by windbg?
I use .dvalloc on user mode but not working on kernel mode

thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to allocate kernel memory through `windbg -k` or are you trying to allocate user-space memory through `windbg -k`?

Comment: Windows' kernel debugger engine API does not provide an interface to allocate memory, so there is likely no WinDbg command to do so.